# Inline widget-like templates in MODx

Tags: php, modx

I'm developing my first ever MODx site and I need to have three blocks on the frontpage that contain headline, picture, image caption, long text and a short text.

For these I would like to create a custom template that allows me to create sub-resources of "Home" with only these five fields (of which one will allow me to upload images).

How can I set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove certain fields from the resource manager? So URL alias isn't available for example.

This can be done using [Managermanager](http://modxcms.com/extras/package/?package=255) then in a chunk you would define your rules as follows, examples taken from a project of mine:

```
mm_hideFields('description', '!1', '13');
mm_hideFields('alias', '!1', '13');
mm_hideFields('menutitle', '!1', '13');
mm_hideFields('content', '!1', '13');
```

These examples are hiding fields from all users who aren't admin (!1) on template 13. A list of the ID's for users and templates can be seen from within the Managermanager plugin.